# How to catch and show custom error page for some error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I added "vimeo/laravel": "^5.8" under laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app for Vimeo support and with free restricted account
I got an error when uploads limit was reached :

```
Vimeo \ Exceptions \ VimeoUploadExceptionPHP 8.2.1110.33.0
Unable to initiate an upload. [Your account doesn't have enough free space to upload this video for the current time period. Go to vimeo.com/upgrade to get more.]
```

[image]

I need to show this error to user, but I do not know how can I make custom error page for this case ?

I have added all error files with command :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

and have 10 files under “resources/views/errors” subdirectory

But anyway I got error as on my printscreen above ... How can I make custom error page for this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your case isn't the easy solution to just implement a try/catch? Something like:

```
        try {
            // Here is your code where you call the Vimeo api
            throw new VimeoUploadException();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Notification::make()
                ->color('danger')
                ->title($e->getMessage())
                ->send();

            // Or if you want a custom page, create one with filament and do something like:
            return $this->redirect(Error::getUrl([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]));
        }
```

Comment: I would make in this in commom laravel app, but in filamentphp saving function somewhere inside of filamentphp and I have how to insert my code inside of save functionality

Comment: Where did you add the code to upload to vimeo?

Comment: In method mutateFormDataBeforeSave of class.
class EditQuizCategory extends EditRecord

Comment: That seems a god idea, I will try to cacth it

Comment: Thank you! That works, but if to make a custom redirect(as in your code) how can I define 
an url itself and the page, based on filamentphp design ?

Comment: Just create a page with `php artisan make:filament-page {name}`, it's what I have done in my example, its called "Error". And you could get the url by getUrl as I did as well